# Cálculo de ocorrência de strings em lista - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda para calcular a quantidade de ocorrências de uma determinada string em uma coluna de uma lista.
Exemplo:

*lista_teste=[['Nome','Idade','Sexo','Profissão'],['Pedro','25','Masculino','Médico']...]*

Ex: Calcular a quantidade de ocorrências por profissão---------

*medico=0*

*professor=0*

***Como fazer a contagem utilizando FOR ou não utilizando FOR***

print("Medicos =",medico,"Professores"=,professor)

Answer (score 4):

Uma boa forma de fazer a contagem é utilizar a classe [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) que já existe em `collections` para esse efeito. Isto faz com que seja necessário importa-la antes de usar:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Após isso e tendo a lista definida, consegue fazer tudo com 3 linhas:

```
profissoes = [pessoa[3] for pessoa in lista_teste[1:]] # apanhar só as profissões
totais = Counter(profissoes) # totalizar
print("Medicos={} Professores={}".format(totais['Professor'], totais['Médico'])) # mostrar
```

Na parte de apanhar apenas as profissões, foi ignorado o primeiro elemento da lista que era o cabeçalho e corresponde ao `lista_teste[1:]` que apanha da posição `1` ao fim. E para cada pessoa foi capturada a quarta coluna que é a coluna na posição `3` com `pessoa[3]` que correspondente à profissão.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qEih04)

É importante de referir que apenas a totalização feita com `Counter(profissoes)` dá lhe um dicionario com todas as profissões existentes e as suas contagens:

```
Counter({'Professor': 3, 'Médico': 2})
```

O que significa que pode deixar o código mais dinâmico se ao invés de indicar fixamente `Professor` e `Médico` utilizar um `for` para mostrar todas as profissões totalizadas:

```
profissoes = [pessoa[3] for pessoa in lista_teste[1:]] # apanhar só as profissões
totais = Counter(profissoes) # totalizar
for profissao,total in totais.items(): # percorrer cada profissão e total
    print("{}={}".format(profissao, total)) # mostrar
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/QURZnf)

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente você deve passar por cada item da lista verificando se a posição relativa à profissão contém "Médico" ou então "Professor" e incrementando o contador respectivo. Algo assim:

```
lista_teste = [
        ['Nome','Idade','Sexo','Profissão'],
        ['Pedro','25','Masculino','Médico'],
        ['José','36','Masculino','Professor'],
        ['Paula','47','Feminino','Policial'],
        ['Pedro','58','Masculino','Professor'],
        ['Marcos','49','Masculino','Médico'],
        ['Daniela','30','Feminino','Professor'],
        ['Heitor','21','Masculino','Médico'],
        ['Carlos','32','Masculino','Professor'],
        ['Alice','43','Feminino','Médico'],
        ['Ricardo','54','Masculino','Mecânico'],
        ['Maria','65','Feminino','Professor'],
        ]

medicos = 0
professores = 0

for pessoa in lista_teste[1:]:
    if pessoa[3] is 'Médico':
        medicos += 1
    elif pessoa[3] is 'Professor':
        professores +=1

print('Total de {} médico(s) e de {} Professor(es).'
    .format(medicos, professores))
```

O que o `for` faz é iterar com cada elemento da lisa 'lista_teste' a partir do 2º item (o "[1:]" que dizer do 2º elemento até o final, a lista começa em 0) colocando seu conteúdo na variável 'pessoa', que também é uma lista.

Daí é verificar o 4º elemento desta  verificando o conteúdo do 4º elemento, a profissão, e cuidando de incrementar 'medicos' ou 'professores' dependendo do caso. Repare que há duas profissões que não são contadas, as deixei de propósito para que você possa fazer seus testes.

Claro, este é um exemplo bem mais didático do que prático.

Comment: Caso eu necessite criar uma função para adicionar as colunas de uma lista em outra lista, e que seja na mesma ordem, como eu poderia realizar esta função.

Comment: Oi, basta usar o método `.append()` e acrescentar os itens da nova linha, por exemplo: `lista_teste.append(['Alice','43','Feminino','Médico'])`.